# active reports always sends to default printer

Tags: printing, activereports

I want to print to a network printer from active reports but it always prints to default printer without throwing error.
Once I try to print with the .net printdocument library it print to specified printer.

I don't know why it is printing to default printer when using activereports.

Answer (score 2):

Set the [PrinterName property](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/??GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Extensibility.v7~GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Extensibility.Printing.Printer~PrinterName.html) of the Printer object. Something like the following:

```
viewer.Document.Printer.PrinterName = "TheNetworkPrinterName";
viewer.Print();
```

The value of the `PrinterName` property should be the exact name from windows. To get a list of the valid printer names on a given system you can enumerate the list of printers using PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters. An example of enumerating the available printers is in [the MSDN documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.installedprinters.aspx).

If you try something and find it doesn't work give us more detailed information and we'll try to help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I'm already assigning the printer name. But it still prints to default printer. Here is a sample which reproduces the problem: https://hotfile.com/dl/214941957/a8b4362/PrintingSample.rar.html

Comment: By the way I have listed the printers with InstalledPrinters and used the named as shown on the list.

Answer (score 0):

Change printer in end user designer.

Grapecityteam answer:

For a SectionReport, you could inject a Script to change the default printer when the report is loaded, in the LayoutChanged event of the Designer as given below:

```
private void OnLayoutChanged(object sender, LayoutChangedArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Type == LayoutChangeType.ReportLoad || e.Type == LayoutChangeType.ReportClear)
            {
                reportToolbox.Reorder(reportDesigner);
                reportToolbox.EnsureCategories();
                reportToolbox.Refresh();
                RefreshExportEnabled();
                CreateReportExplorer();
                splitContainerMiddle.Panel2Collapsed = reportDesigner.ReportType == DesignerReportType.Section;

                if (reportDesigner.ReportType == DesignerReportType.Section)
                {
                    string script = string.Empty;
                    script += "public void ActiveReport_ReportStart()";
                    script += "{";
                    script += "rpt.Document.Printer.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[3];";
                    script += "}";
                    (reportDesigner.Report as SectionReport).ScriptLanguage = "C#";
                    (reportDesigner.Report as SectionReport).Script = script;
                }

            }
```

thanks to Grapecity Sales and Support